# GitLab Review: What do I do if I need to customize something after a PR vs Master?

Tags: git, gitlab

I just made my first merge request in a already existing project. We work with GitLab and this was the workflow:

- pushed my branch (for Example: ABC-901)
- make the Merge Request against the master via GitLab

**Problem:** The reviewer later asked me to adjust something via the comments.

**My question**: How do I proceed? Can I make the changes in my branch ABC-901 or do I need to create a new branch that derives from the old branch for this?

What happens if I, in the existing branch ABS-001 make my changes and push again? That would be my favored approach. But I don't know if it's right.

Comment: While you can do it either way, the point of the review is to suggest changes. IMO, you should make the changes in the same branch.

Comment: @nullptr Thank you very much for your comment. So I will make the changes in my current local branch. Push them to the stage and commit. After that a push against my remote branch (ABC-001) on GitLab.  `git push origin ABC-001`. Correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: @nullptr All right and thanks again. Then I can do so and then go to the end of the day. Many greetings to India!